# Facebook-like header / Top bar

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to compose this facebook-like top bar (or header, I don't know) with some CSS. I think it is pretty easy, and well, the first results indeed were.

I've set the bar with a `fixed` position, with its `top` and `left` properties set to 0. Its `padding` is set to `4px` and it works great; Just as I wanted it.

But the question now is... what about the content? I could simply wrap it inside a `<div>` and relatively position it a few `em`s to its bottom. But then, wouldn't it hide the content's bottom in case of it surpassing the browser's max height? And also, that could cause some size incompatibilities with *certain* browsers (I hate IE).

I'm sorry if this has already been asked here, I could not find such question. And to be more clear, I do not want any kinda "dinamically-updating" headers -- at least not yet. And I think I can do that with some HTML5.

The main question here is: what is the best way of doing such header? Is the `position: fixed` the real way to go? And, if so, how is the best way of displaying the content?

TIA, André

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by Facebook-like. They may change their interface, rendering your question obsolete, unless you mention the specific things you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Good point. But how can I describe it? I think "fixed top bar with no content hiding on content's bottom" is a little too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:fixed` will do.

Simple add margin to the top of your content. (same as the height of your header.)

So, when you're at the top of the page, your header will cover the margin. When you scroll down, it will behave as expected. And the browser will not hide the bottom part.

Comment: Hmm. You mean like, some Javascript to get the header's height (because I won't set it via CSS) and set it as the content's top margin on the DOM Content Load?

Comment: I was expecting that your header height is statically set through CSS. It's up to you. But do you really want a resizing header ? Wouldn't that make it a little awkward for the user ?

Comment: Not really a resizing header. It's just that, the way I've designed it now, I didn't set the height statically. Its height is simply created by the font's size plus its padding. The Javascript is an easy part. I'll count this answer as accepted as soon as the question times out. Thanks.